# Which data structure is used for ready queue in operating system?

Tags: operating-system

To implement round-robin algorithm, the "circular queue" is considered as the best data structure.

Comment: "To implement round-robin algorithm, the "circular queue" is considered as the best data structure." What do you mean with this? What has it got to do with your question?

Comment: Which Operating System?

Comment: For Linux see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38510965/2626313

Comment: @xmojmr Wiindows

Comment: @HansPetterTaugbølKragset my professor told me Doubly linked list with some type of priority levels is used for ready queue. But in galvin book that statement is given.

Comment: I wish every copy of that stupid book could be rounded up and burned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which data structure is used for ready queue in Windows Operating System?

I don't know but I have found some articles which might contain the answer:

1. [Processes, Threads, and Jobs in the Windows Operating System by Mark E. Russinovich and David A. Solomon](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2233328&seqNum=7) - search for "ready queue"
2. [Internals of Windows Thread by Mahesh Bailwal](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/662735/Internals-of-Windows-Thread) - search for "ready queue"
3. [Google query: site:reactos.org "ready queue"](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Areactos.org+%22ready+queue%22&oq=site%3Areactos.org+%22ready+queue%22)

According the article #1 there are fields in the Processor Region Control Block kernel object (PRCB) called `ReadySummary` (Bitmask 32 bits), `DeferredReadyListHead` (Single linked list), `DispatcherReadyListHead` (Array of 32 list entries) which implement the ready queue.

You can use source code of the `ReactOS` Operating System (article #3) to learn more about the Windows behavior.

Comment: Thanks for writing valuable info.

Comment: @Ankit you are welcome. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

> Which data structure is used for ready queue in operating system?

This depends on the operating system. For most modern operating system this is some sort of algorithm made to be as fair as possible. This can be a round robin, fifo, CFS (red-black tree), or some other algorithm. The ready queue may be split into priority levels.

When a process is created or unblocked, it can be appended at the back of the list/queue. It may also be left in place and skipped as long as it is blocked.

What is used also depends on weather preemption is in use or not, which it is by default in general purpose operating systems (Linux/Windows/MacOS).

Comment: Can you provide some sort of proof (Wikipedia article or something similar) for the "_for most modern ones it's a FIFO queue_"?

Comment: Thanks for making me look into this, I may have been a bit too quick on the gun. Will edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks @HansPetterTaugbølKragset

Answer (score 1):

The round-robin scheduler chooses the processes on a first-come, first-served basis. The first to arrive is the first to be executed. Each process is executed for a short time called time-slice. When the time-slice expires, a timer interrupt occurs. Then the first in the queue is chosen to be executed and the interrupted process is placed at the end of the queue. This FIFO feature favors the implementation of the ready queue as a FIFO queue structure.